# Command-line Powercenter test tool

Tags: command-line, informatica-powercenter

Does Informatica Powercenter offer a way to test its functions on the command line? E.g., I would like to test the result of md5('someval').

I am using Informatica in a linux environment.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no such command line tool to test Informatica functions.

What you can do is, run a mapping (any valid mapping with an expression transformation) in debugger, step into an Expression. Right-click on the Expression transformation and click Evaluate. In the Evaluate window you can write any function to test.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Informatica has that function to test, but did you try to run 
the md5sum command ?

Example
md5sum filename.txt
d6d0bbcb172774893b04d48ce16242a4  filename.txt

Syntax and Options

```
md5sum [OPTION]… [FILE]…

Short Option    Long Option Option Description
-b  –binary read in binary mode
-c  –check  read MD5 sums from the FILEs and check them
-t  –text   read in text mode (default)
–quiet  don’t print OK for each successfully verified file
–status don’t output anything, status code shows success
-w  –warn   warn about improperly formatted checksum lines
```